# Ubuntu installation VS UEFI on Dell XPS 13 9343

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, dell

I have heard that there are problems with Ubuntu on the Dell XPS 13 9343, however - I cannot even make the boot menu pop-up when booting from an installation pendrive (lastest Ubuntu, lastest Unetbootin).

When booting from a pendrive - all I can see is the Grub console. I tried to turn off some options in BIOS (Secure Boot AFAIR) but this changes absolutely nothing.

So here are my 3 questions:

1. How can I configure the BIOS on my XPS to be able to install Ubuntu on it?
2. Is this reasonable to install Ubuntu on this laptop, since there are so many problems (sound, touchpad, etc) with it?
3. How is this - there is a "developer" edition of this laptop - with Ubuntu preinstalled, so I assume that Dell took care of the installation and configuration, and it should work fine, so why there are so many problems with a clean installation of Ubuntu on this computer having the "normal" version (not the developer one)?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Leave purely opinion based questions like your question 2. What is very reasonable for me may not be so for you. This forum is not for [these types of questions](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Dell has the resources to make changes to the (pre-installed version of the) system files where needed to make Ubuntu work with their hardware. These changes will be eventually "upstreamed" and be merged into some future version of Ubuntu. Once that happens the new Dell XPS 13 will work out of the box with that version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't speak to the Dell specifically, but you might want to check [my page on Linux UEFI installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for some generic tips about how to install on modern computers without falling into some common traps.

Answer (score 0):

I have received from Dell the [Dell iso image for 14.04](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxuBIWrIIPFwTjVBZWxIWmx4VGs&authuser=2). This should load the default Dell BIOS.

An update to [A04 BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=133FN) will be necessary to avoid some issues with the keyboard. Additionally, you'll want to [download](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/mediagallery/20441258) and install the packages to avoid issues with your trackpad; [click here](http://www.dell.com/Support/Article/us/en/04/SLN297219) for information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I am not sure if I can PM you, I can't find a PM option in the dashboard when on Your page :(

Comment: If it is not a problem, could You contact me about this ISO image by email? heretical at o2.pl

Comment: Sorry, @dziki. I just saw this. I added the image link for download from my Google-Docs to this Post.

Comment: See http://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Dell-Ubuntu-XPS-2015-14.04

Comment: @NotMy1RealName - thanks! Still, I cannot install it properly... Doesnt matter what installation option I choose, upon the end of the installation I get: "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot".

Comment: @dziki , Sorry, Friend. I nuked the factory installation and wiped everything to get back to factory. Let us know if you make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

I would load Bios A03 or A04. Then I would install Ubuntu 15.04. This is the setup I have. I currently have the bios set to UEFI and Secure Boot. Those options work.

I have no audio issues, but did have to use special firmware to get bluetooth working. [Instructions Here](https://ftbeowulf.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/dell-xps-13-9343-developer-edition-bluetooth-firmware/).